# Should I ONLY have to worry about new and match them with deletes?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a C++ code in which I have multiple data types. Importantly, I have a class:

```
class coordinate{
    int x, y;
    public:
     void set_values(int, int);
}
```

I then might say:

```
coordinate* origin = new coordinate;
```

Obviously, to recover memory allocated to origin I would finally say:

```
delete(origin);
```

So far, so good...

My question is are there any other datatypes whose deletion/destruction I MUST ABSOLUTELY MANUALLY take care of to prevent memory leakage?

The other datatypes in question are:

string (an object of this datatype seems to have an end() function), stringstream, char [].

For eg. I have a function setname() that gets called from main() repeatedly that does this:

```
void setname(){

    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        string NAME = "Point ";
        stringstream s;
        s << k;
        NAME += s.str();
        char name[7];
        strcpy(name,NAME.c_str());
        /*  some other stuff... */
        NAME.end(); //<--------------is stuff like this really needed?
//will memory held by NAME, s and name be automatically released as k increments?
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::string::end()` is part of the STL iteration mechanism. It has nothing to do with memory management. :)

Comment: Did you think to look up what `std::string::end()` does?

Comment: Be sure to type `delete origin` not `delete(origin)`.

Comment: @Chance: They're equivalent. `delete origin` is the common style, but either one is functionally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. If your code allocates anything (a `string`, an instance of `coordinate` class, a `stringstream` etc.) with `new`, some code (maybe yours) should `delete` it. Otherwise, if you create a string on stack and pass it around with copy constructors, you don't have to delete it.

And: `NAME.end()` is not needed at all. The function `end()` actually returns an iterator, pointing past the end of the string; it doesn't do any clean-up. So in your code the call to `end()` is not needed.

Comment: So...short of an allocation with new I can just be blind to worries about memory leakage?

Comment: If you didn't allocate the memory, _usually_ you don't need to deallocate it, too. However there are some special cases: some functions are allocating the data for you, expecting you to deallocate them. But this practice is quite rare, and must be properly described in the appropriate documentation.

Comment: @Tryer: Ideally, yes. Unless programmers of the underlying things you use have messed up, which happens quite frequently. But as long as YOU match every new with a delete and don't use any obscure memory functions (malloc...) or C string functions, you should be fine.

Comment: Great. I will sleep well tonight. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Every `new` should match a `delete`, every `new []` to a `delete []`, and every `malloc` to a `free` (but don't use them in C++...)

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

The idea there is to bind resources to the lifetime of objects on the stack. Popular examples are [smart pointers](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm), [locks](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks) and [file handles](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/).

Answer (score 2):

**As a general rule:** If you `new` it, `delete` it. If you `new[]` it, `delete[]` it. If you `malloc()` it, `free()` it.

Otherwise, you *generally* don't have to do anything. (System-specific stuff like `GlobalAlloc()` on Windows or `CFStringCreate()` on Mac OS X/iOS has its own rules. Refer to your manual/FAQ/MSDN for information on these system-specific APIs.)

Comment: Note that Win32 APIs specifically seem to have no rules at all, other than "check the documentation for every single function.... And read it veeery thoroughly. Some require you to allocate a buffer which the system will then deallocate. Sometimes it's the other way around, the API gives you a system-allocated buffer that you have to deallocate. Sometime syou have to do both, sometimes neither. And the functions you're supposed to use to allocate or deallocate varies as well.

Comment: Which is why God invented abstraction libraries. /me shudders

Answer (score 0):

You can always investigate the [boost::shared_ptr](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).  You still have to do the 'new', but the delete is handled internally by the shared ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++0x/TR1 shared_ptr<> if you can, they are absolutely amazing, some say with performance implications, but still, think about other alternatives only if profiler complains about shared_ptr. Shared pointers are thread safe and with very good behavior on reassign (shared_ptr<>::reset will split the references).

The only thing you should look out for is new vs new[], that's why I like c type memory allocators so much more (calloc, malloc, free) if I don't need constructors and destructors (ie. POD types).

For c type allocator you would use: `shared_ptr<char> charptr((char*)calloc(10, sizof(char)), free);`

P.S.: For other objects, watch out for kernel handles and GDI objects (at least on windows), they do not exactly leak memory in a classic sense, but have to be closed.

Also, c type functions often return malloc'd pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no. You use RAII for this - it's exception-safe.

Basically, when an object of a custom type goes out of scope in C++, it calls a special function (called the destructor). This is used to clean up all resources. It's applied automatically and, in reality, is called in all scenarios in which your program could reasonably continue, and a few that it can't.

What this means is that you never, ever have to free the memory created by a custom type- it should free itself. You will not have to free the memory allocated by std::string, nor std::stringstream. std::string::end() is about ending iteration. Typically, for any resources that require custom freeing, you will wrap them in a custom type, so that they no longer require manual freeing.

For custom types allocated with new, you can use auto_ptr, which immediately destroys the object when it goes out of scope and frees the memory, or you can use shared_ptr, which "shares" the object between all instances that point to it via some magic. There are other types of smart pointer, and for any given resource, you can write your own custom management type. This drastically increases the safety of your program for no performance loss.

Also, you should never, ever, ever use char* or any related types (char[], etc) to store strings in C++. Use std::string. Your current code is unmaintainable, as it will die or may cause random bugs if you need more than 7 characters. The C-style string functions (strcpy) are similarly extremely deprecated and should not be used.

(of course, there are exceptions to every rule, but C-style strings, you have to be very advanced to utilize their upsides correctly).

The general rule is, if you ever call a function that frees a resource outside of a destructor, you have almost certainly written your program wrong.